# conditional hover with class name

Tags: html, css

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>list</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.mainList:hover li.childList{
            color:red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="mainList">111</li>   
    <li>111
        <ul>
            <li class="childList">222</li>
            <li class="childList">222</li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
    <li>111</li>    
    <li class="mainList">111</li>       
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to change color my nested list items whenever user hover on first child and last child of main list. Why my above code does not work and what is your suggestion with first-child (last-child) selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not correctly using the selectors. From your markup, this should work.

```
li.mainList:hover + li li.childList{
            color:red;
        }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rtx1wcxf/) is the working fiddle.

Comment: That doesn't work. The requirement was for the hover effect to work on the first **and last** list items.

Comment: @Quentin that is true but I assume he is having control over the markup that you've already explained pretty well. But this could be the possible pure CSS solution.

Comment: I don't understand how "having control over the markup" would solve the problem (at least not without changing the content so it doesn't mean the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

> Why my above code does not work

Because you have used a descendant combinator and the nested list is not a descendant of the element being hovered.

> what is your suggestion with first-child (last-child) selectors

To not use them.

---

You can't walk back up the tree to get a hover on the last child to affect the descendants of one of its previous siblings using CSS.

Use JavaScript (a mouseover listener) instead.

Comment: I just wanna use HTML, CSS

Comment: @AFN — I refer you back to the answer you just commented on. It hasn't become any less impossible in the last minute.